# Context provided in parent component?

Tags: android, dagger-2

With dagger 2 I created an Application lifecycle scoped graph and within in an Activity lifecycle scoped graph.  In the Activity graph I want to provide the same Picasso instance to all activities

AppModule:

```
@Module
public final class AppModule {
    Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    ActivityComponent activityComponent(ActivityModule activityModule);
}
```

ActivityModule:

```
@Module
public final class ActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Picasso providePicasso(Context context, OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new 
OkHttp3Downloader(client)).build();
}
```

ActivityComponent:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = ActivityModule.class)
@PerActivity
public interface ActivityComponent {
    FragmentComponent fragmentComponent(FragmentModule fragmentModule);
}
```

An error occurs in ActivityModule providePicasso complaining that the Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

ActivityComponent is a subcomponent of AppComponent, it should have access to everything in its parent, and AppModule provides the Context via provideContext doesn't it??

Comment: Your subcomponent is scoped `@PerActivity` but in it you are providing Picasso as a `@Singleton` from a wider scope. If you want to provide Picasso as a `@Singleton` you can do it at the level of `AppComponent`